# Selenium Webdriver in Azure Pipeline - Logs and Screenshots don't appear in Artifacts anymore

Tags: c#, azure, selenium, pipeline

I'm uploading a Selenium Webdriver project (C#) on Azure.

I implemented logs and screenshots on errors, and for a couple of weeks, they appeared correctly in the Artifacts after the test finishes.

Now, for some reason, they don't appear in the Artifact folder anymore (the other artifact files appear correctly)

In my local execution, they do work flawlessly on any error I encounter.

Is there any setting that could cause this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue.

Turns out I was saving my screenshots to the `Debug` folder, and Azure was creating a `Release` folder.

Just changed the folder and it worked.